# In app purchase displays message "you already own this item." in android

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I am trying to implement in-app. In android, in-app is working perfectly.But, when I **remove** the app from device and **reinstall** it, then after if I try to purchase, it displays this message `(product is Managed and in-app API Version 2)`

[image]

and in log, I have an error  `RESULT_DEVELOPER_ERROR` , then I googled and I found the Version 3 has more number of response codes like `BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED`

So if product is already purchased, the response must be like  `BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED` and this is not possible in Version 2.

Then what should I do ? Do I need to implement Version 3 ?

Answer (score 11):

if you want force to buy product by **every time** then product should be **Unmanaged**.

Products can be of 3 types

1) Managed

2) Unmanaged

3) Subcription

Managed means google it self keep record. so by using same email id user not have to paid its charge e.g. remove ads

Unmanaged means user have to buy every time and will be a charged.  e.g. Pocker chips

This 2 example i have read on developer site..

and refer http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_admin.html

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I do not want to force to buy the product every time. I just want to receive something like "already purchased" notification instead of "RESULT_DEVELOPER_ERROR" when user tries to buy product that he owns already.

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked into `RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS`?

I had pretty much the same problem you describe above.  My code is, for the most part, taken from the [Market Billing Sample Application](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/v2/billing_integrate.html#billing-download).

I added a RESTORE button to my purchase activity which calls the `BillingService.restoreTransactions` routine.

If you search for `RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS` within this page: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/v2/api.html, you'll find that calling that routine re-triggers the `PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED` broadcast.

Which, in my code, triggered the `onPurchaseStateChange` routine and it worked the same way it would on the initial purchase with the `PurchaseState` was set to `PURCHASED`.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up with calling `BillingService.restoreTransactions()` after catching `RESULT_DEVELOPER_ERROR`. Looks odd, but works fine.

Comment: It is better to do the restoration before you try to make a purchase. You can have a "Restore purchased items" button.

Comment: I have a "Restore" button, but I cannot force user to press it instead of the "Buy" button :)