# In app Billing version2 android already own this item? Developer error

Tags: android, in-app-billing, android-billing

In my application i had uploaded manged item, if it already purchase then show item already own this item, but if user  delete it , they can download again free if already purchased. but it giving me error developer error.

APK is sign.
same code version.

```
 05-03 12:36:01.455: D/Finsky(22460): [1] MarketBillingService.sendResponseCode:     Sending     response RESULT_DEVELOPER_ERROR for request  
   05-03 12:36:01.455: I/ALSAModule(1695): Initialized ALSA PLAYBACK device hifi
    05-03 12:36:01.475: I/System.out(22585): responsecodeRecieved
 05-03 12:36:01.485: I/System.out(22585): responsecodeRecieved = =nullRESULT_DEVELOPER_ERROR
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for developer error should be one of

1. Package name inconsistency.
2. Application version mismatch between the developer console and the app that is being used to purchase.
3. Inconsistency in Private Key/ Release signing.

and in Version 2, afaik, there is no specific error code similar to '**ALREADY_PURCHASED**'.

Version 3 has this(**BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED**) and is a bit more simpler to implement. Try that out.

I believe this is similar :
[In app purchase displays message "you already own this item." in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14039778/in-app-purchase-displays-message-you-already-own-this-item-in-android?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks. but the developer error not giving in response when new item buying... Version 2 what response will br if already own

Comment: It will be a generic 'RESULT_DEVELOPER_ERROR' only. I think you cannot get the exact reason in v2. One way for you to workaround this problem  would be to restore Transactions after you get the 'DEVELOPER_ERROR' .

Comment: in this error occurs then this gives me a DWeveleper error i will handle it but the play store intent open two time on single it is not understandable...:(