# In AppBilling - Purchase issue - Google sample code itself is not working

Tags: android, google-play-services, in-app-billing

I was running the Trivial drive sample application for testing InAppBilling. Once the item is purchased, "Item Added" window appears, but on clicking OK, it seems like a new purchase call occurs and google play shows "Error - You already own this item". The screencast video of the issue is attached. *Why the sample code provided by Google is not working?* . I can't go forward unless this issue is resolved. Thanks in advance.

[Screencast video showing the issue](https://youtu.be/mwcDZZ3CN44)

[Trivial drive application code](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/tree/master/TrivialDrive)

Comment: Have you tried reading this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14039778/in-app-purchase-displays-message-you-already-own-this-item-in-android

Comment: @d.datul1990 Hi, I had checked that. No use. In new InApp version 3, there are only two types of products: Managed and Subscriptions (No unmanaged product)

Comment: I too have experienced the same issue. I'm not sure. I think it because of recurring purchasing and consumption of the same product many times.  It would be great if anyone could help out.